# rails: passing additional parameter with Model.save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with an internal API application. When I use my front-end app to request information, i can pass an additional parameter with the request like this:

```
Model.find(id, :params => {:locale => I8n.locale})
or
Model.get(:custom_api_call, :locale => I18n.locale)
```

Is there a place to do that with Model.save or Model.update_attributes? For instance, this doesn't work:

```
Model.save(:params => {:locale => I18n.locale})
Model.save(:locale => I18n.locale)
Model.update_attributes(:locale => I18n.locale)
Model.update_attributes(:params => {:locale => I18n.locale})
```

As you can imagine, those simply add :locale to the attributes sent to my API.

Better yet! If someone knows how to pass :locale => I18n.locale as a parameter with every communication, that would let me dry up a lot of my code.

Thank you for your time

Comment: why pass local in every communication? seems like something that should be stored in the db / or in a cookie when the user first requests the application.

Comment: don't I have to pass it with a request in order for the API to know the value of locale? Will the API be able to access a cookie since the browser won't touch the API directly?

Comment: UPDATE: In this particular case, I realized that I don't need to pass locale on save after all b/c I don't need it for what I am doing. I am still curious, however, on the above comment b/c I still am sending it with every .find and .get call. But for now, this question can be shelved.